# XLRD, .xls files, python

Tags: python, xls, xlrd

I have .xls file and I need to center align all the data in that excel file using python(any library).
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is rather unspecific. Please show us what you have already tried with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will increase your chances to get a good solution from the community.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

def align(data):
    return pd.DataFrame('text-align: center', index=data.index, columns=data.columns)

df = pd.read_excel('filename.xls') # load excel as pandas dataframe
df = df.style.apply(align, axis=None) # apply text alignment

with pd.ExcelWriter('output_filename.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer) # write to excel
```